# How to find repeating sequence of characters in a given array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

My problem is to find the repeating sequence of characters in the given array. simply, to identify the pattern in which the characters are appearing.

```
   .---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.
1: | J | A | M | E | S | O | N | J | A | M | E | S | O | N |
   '---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'
```

```
   .---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.
2: | R | O | N | R | O | N | R | O | N | R | O | N | R | O | N |
   '---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'
```

```
   .---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.
3: | S | H | A | M | I | L | S | H | A | M | I | L |
   '---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'
```

```
   .---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.
4: | C | A | R | P | E | N | T | E | R | C | A | R | P | E | N | T | E | R |
   '---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'---'
```

---

#### Example

Given the previous data, the result should be:

1. *`"JAMESON"`*
2. *`"RON"`*
3. *`"SHAMIL"`*
4. *`"CARPENTER"`*

---

#### Question

- How to deal with this problem efficiently?

Comment: Removed the [aptitude] tag because it's used primarily to refer to the APT client. Also, should this be tagged [language-agnostic] instead of [java] and [c]?

Comment: Is the array containing exactly the repeated text, or is it larger ? Is the repeated text starting on the first cell or can it start anywhere in the array ?

Comment: Pay attention to stuff like `BARBARABARBARABARBARA` (repeating `BARBARA`, not `BAR`)

Comment: you can look at this Knuth Morris Pratt String Matching Algorithm,which basically detects characters match.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For your examples, my first approach would be to

1. get the first character of the array (for your last example, that would be `C`)
2. get the index of the next appearance of that character in the array (e.g. 9)
3. if it is found, search for the next appearance of the substring between the two appearances of the character (in this case `CARPENTER`)
4. if it is found, you're done (and the result is this substring).

Of course, this works only for a very limited subset of possible arrays, where the same word is repeated over and over again, starting from the beginning, without stray characters in between, and its first character is not repeated within the word. But all your examples fall into this category - and I prefer the simplest solution which could possibly work :-)

If the repeated word contains the first character multiple times (e.g. `CACTUS`), the algorithm can be extended to look for subsequent occurrences of that character too, not only the first one (so that it finds the whole repeated word, not only a substring of it).

Note that this extended algorithm would give a different result for your second example, namely `RONRON` instead of `RON`.

Comment: +1 for simplicity and linear time solution. However, I understood the problem differently. I guess that the question should specify whether characters can repeat in the pattern, and whether we are looking for the largest or smallest pattern that repeats itself.

Comment: assuming the word never repeats the first letter is pretty much throwing up your hands and going home.

Comment: @Jonathan, in case you haven't noticed, I actually describe how to deal with that case :-)

Comment: @sagivo, care to explain why you think so?

Answer (score 27):

**Tongue-in-cheek O(NlogN) solution**

Perform an FFT on your string (treating characters as numeric values).  Every peak in the resulting graph corresponds to a substring periodicity.

Comment: As you mention the FFT, it got me thinking about using a cross-correlation (whichever method is used) to find matches of the substring in the sequence.  Normally my caveman brute-force approach, if I couldn't use an off-the-shelf regex library, would be the "walk the sequence, try to match" approach.  But your answer got me thinking -- I wonder if/when a cross correlation would be more efficient.  Probably depends on the length of the pattern, the length of the sequence to search, etc... but anyway, your answer got me thinking ("out of the box" as Jonathan said).  Thanks.

Comment: Cross-correlation and doing a Fourier transform are effectively the same thing (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).  For anything other than quite small values of *N*, the FFT will be more efficient.

Comment: Could you explain why every peak corresponds to a substring periodicity? Unfortunately, I cannot fully grasp the idea. I only know FFT for frequency analysis in music (there, multiple frequencies overlay at the same time; but when analyzing text we've got a straight sequence of characters). How does this match up?

Answer (score 6):

In Python, you can leverage regexes thus:

```
def recurrence(text):
    import re
    for i in range(1, len(text)/2 + 1):
        m = re.match(r'^(.{%d})\1+$'%i, text)
        if m: return m.group(1)

recurrence('abcabc') # Returns 'abc'
```

I'm not sure how this would translate to Java or C. (That's one of the reasons I like Python, I guess. :-)

Answer (score 2):

First write a method that find repeating substring `sub` in the container string as below.

```
boolean findSubRepeating(String sub, String container);
```

Now keep calling this method with increasing substring in the container, first try 1 character  substring, then 2 characters, etc going upto `container.length/2`.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode

```
len = str.length
for (i in 1..len) {
   if (len%i==0) {
      if (str==str.substr(0,i).repeat(len/i)) {
         return str.substr(0,i)
      }
   }
}
```

Note: For brevity, I'm inventing a "repeat" method for strings, which isn't actually part of Java's string; "abc".repeat(2)="abcabc"

Answer (score 1):

Using C++:

```
//Splits the string into the fragments of given size
//Returns the set of of splitted strings avaialble
set<string> split(string s, int frag)
{
    set<string> uni;
    int len = s.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i+= frag)
    {
        uni.insert(s.substr(i, frag));
    }

    return uni;
}

int main()
{

    string out;
    string s = "carpentercarpenter";
    int len = s.length();

      //Optimistic approach..hope there are only 2 repeated strings
      //If that fails, then try to break the strings with lesser number of
      //characters
    for(int i = len/2; i>1;--i)
    {
        set<string> uni = split(s,i);
        if(uni.size() == 1)
        {
            out = *uni.begin();
            break;
        }
    }

    cout<<out;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that comes to my mind is trying all repeating sequences of lengths that divide length(S) = N. There is a maximum of N/2 such lengths, so this results in a O(N^2) algorithm.

But i'm sure it can be improved...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general solution to the problem, that will find repeating subsequences within an sequence (of anything), where the subsequences do not have to start at the beginning, nor immediately follow each other.

given an sequence b[0..n], containing the data in question, and a threshold t being the minimum subsequence length to find,

```
l_max = 0, i_max = 0, j_max = 0;
for (i=0; i<n-(t*2);i++) {
  for (j=i+t;j<n-t; j++) {
    l=0;
    while (i+l<j && j+l<n && b[i+l] == b[j+l])
      l++;
    if (l>t) {
      print "Sequence of length " + l + " found at " + i + " and " + j);
      if (l>l_max) {
        l_max = l;
        i_max = i;
        j_max = j;
      }
    }
  }
}
if (l_max>t) {
  print "longest common subsequence found at " + i_max + " and " + j_max + " (" + l_max + " long)";
}
```

Basically:

1. Start at the beginning of the data, iterate until within 2*t of the end (no possible way to have two distinct subsequences of length t in less than 2*t of space!)
2. For the second subsequence, start at least t bytes beyond where the first sequence begins.
3. Then, reset the length of the discovered subsequence to 0, and check to see if you have a common character at i+l and j+l. As long as you do, increment l.
   When you no longer have a common character, you have reached the end of your common subsequence. 
   If the subsequence is longer than your threshold, print the result.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this out myself and wrote some code for this (written in C#) with a lot of comments. Hope this helps someone:

```cs
// Check whether the string contains a repeating sequence.
public static bool ContainsRepeatingSequence(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return false;

    for (int i=0; i<str.Length; i++)
    {
        // Every iteration, cut down the string from i to the end.
        string toCheck = str.Substring(i);

        // Set N equal to half the length of the substring. At most, we have to compare half the string to half the string. If the string length is odd, the last character will not be checked against, but it will be checked in the next iteration.
        int N = toCheck.Length / 2;

        // Check strings of all lengths from 1 to N against the subsequent string of length 1 to N.
        for (int j=1; j<=N; j++)
        {
            // Check from beginning to j-1, compare against j to j+j.
            if (toCheck.Substring(0, j) == toCheck.Substring(j, j)) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Feel free to ask any questions if it's unclear why it works.

Answer (score 0):

and here is a concrete working example:

```
/* find greatest repeated substring */
char *fgrs(const char *s,size_t *l)
{
  char *r=0,*a=s;
  *l=0;
  while( *a )
  {
    char *e=strrchr(a+1,*a);
    if( !e )
      break;
    do {
      size_t t=1;
      for(;&a[t]!=e && a[t]==e[t];++t);
      if( t>*l )
        *l=t,r=a;
      while( --e!=a && *e!=*a );
    } while( e!=a && *e==*a );
    ++a;
  }
  return r;
}

  size_t t;
  const char *p;
  p=fgrs("BARBARABARBARABARBARA",&t);
  while( t-- ) putchar(*p++);
  p=fgrs("0123456789",&t);
  while( t-- ) putchar(*p++);
  p=fgrs("1111",&t);
  while( t-- ) putchar(*p++);
  p=fgrs("11111",&t);
  while( t-- ) putchar(*p++);
```

Comment: oops `p=fgrs("BARBARABARBARAB-RBARA", &t);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you define "efficiently". For easy/fast implementation you could do this in Java:

```
    private static String findSequence(String text) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\1+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        return matcher.matches() ? matcher.group(1) : null;
    }
```

it tries to find the shortest string (`.+?`) that must be repeated at least once (`\1+`) to match the entire input text.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I came up with using the queue, it passed all the test cases of a similar problem in codeforces. Problem No is 745A.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    string s, s1, s2; cin >> s; queue<char> qu; qu.push(s[0]); bool flag = true; int ind = -1;
    s1 = s.substr(0, s.size() / 2);
    s2 = s.substr(s.size() / 2);
    if(s1 == s2)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<s1.size(); i++)
        {
            s += s1[i];
        }
    }
    //cout << s1 << " " << s2 << " " << s << "\n";
    for(int i=1; i<s.size(); i++)
    {
        if(qu.front() == s[i]) {qu.pop();}
        qu.push(s[i]);
    }
    int cycle = qu.size();

    /*queue<char> qu2 = qu; string str = "";
    while(!qu2.empty())
    {
        cout << qu2.front() << " ";
        str += qu2.front();
        qu2.pop();
    }*/


    while(!qu.empty())
    {
        if(s[++ind] != qu.front()) {flag = false; break;}
        qu.pop();
    }
    flag == true ? cout << cycle : cout << s.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pattern(y):  #y = sequence list
     a=y[0]
     s=0 #start
     e=0 #end
     for i in range(len(y)):
        if y[i]==a:
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if y[:j]==y[i:i+j]:
            s,e=i,i+j
            continue
     if e==len(y)-1 and s==0:
        return "No repeating sequence found"
     else:
        return s,e,e-s   #period e-s
```

you can use this code. This works in two cases - 1.whole sequence is periodic  2. if two or more than two sequence got repeated in sequence. it will return you start and end point of repeating sequence if available.

Answer (score -1):

I'd convert the array to a String object and use regex

Comment: This is NOT an answer! Edit: I see this is old! I hope you have bettered yourself in this stretch of time!

Answer (score -1):

Put all your character in an array e.x. a[]

```
i=0; j=0;
for( 0 < i < count ) 
{
if (a[i] == a[i+j+1])
    {++i;}
else
    {++j;i=0;}
}
```

Then the ratio of (i/j) = repeat count in your array.
You must pay attention to limits of `i` and `j`, but it is the simple solution.